# localhost:3000 database adapter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

If my localhost:3000 page is showing "Database adapter  postgresql", does this mean `postgresql` is running and not `mysql`?

Background: I originally installed `postgresql` and later installed mysql.

My `database.yml` file currently contains the following so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: projects
  username: root
  password: 
  pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

**1:** add `gem 'mysql2'` in your gemfile

**2:** run `bundle install`

**3:** `mysql -u root` # for do login and create db

**4:**  **mysql>** `create Database projects;`

Hope this help you !!!

Comment: @mpath Have my answer work for you or still have any issues?